# What is the name of this character used to indicate social sharing?

Tags: html, character, symbols

Is there an HTML code for this character? If there is, can you all let me know what it is? If there is no HTML code for this character, can you let me know what this glyph is called? I had been looking all over the place for it, and today I happened to stumble upon it.

[image: Unknown character]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most icon libraries use a variant of **"share"** as the terminology for this icon.

Here are a couple of examples :

**Material Design Icons** calls it [share](https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=share&icon=share&style=baseline).

**AntDesign** calls it [share-alt](https://iconify.design/icon-sets/ant-design/share-alt-outlined.html)

Answer (score 1):

That is the share icon. I think FontAwesome has it, or if you want exactly like that you can search for it on FlatIcon.

[Link for FlatIcon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/share-alt?style=solid)

Something that I usually do is getting all the icons that I will use on the project and make it into a font. I use this service to help me with that: https://icomoon.io/app/

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called a SHARE ICON

Comment: The Google link isn't useful because Google could change their search structures. In the future, please [add more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)